# What to do when a question posts sensitive/personalliy-identifying information accidentally?

Tags: discussion

On at least one ocassion I've come across a question which posts log data that contains potentially sensitive date, i.e. session id, org id, ip addresses, etc.  I've edited the post to remove them and replaced it with XXXXXXs.  However, that sensitive data is still in the revision log should anyone care to look there.

Am I being a worry-wart here, or is this something we should be helping people save themselves from?  And if it does happen is there a more permanent way to remove that data from the publics view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just let admins know that (flag the post)

And we can ask to have the revisions deleted.